linker errors LNK2019 integrating Lua 503 into a C++ game engine using Sol v3.2.1
I'm trying to integrate Lua 503 into a C++ game engine using Sol v3.2.1 as a wrapper. Everything is included properly in the project and builds fine until i try using Sol, then i start getting linker errors.
#include "Engine.h"

#include <sol.hpp>

void TestLua()
{
    sol::state lua; // <-- This is causing linker errors
}

int main(int argv, char* argc[])
{
    TestLua();

    return 0;
}

Solution Explorer file structure
I'm unfamiliar with integrating scripting, i'm just following along with a course so i am unsure of what to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Seems like sol is header-only, so a linker error is probably failing to link against Lua itself. Looks like Visual Studio, so Windows? Your solution shows a liblua54.a which is probably a static Lua library, but not for Windows. A Windows static library would usually be .lib. So I would suggest double checking that you have a compatible static library (if that's how you want to link -- or link dynamically, or compile Lua from source as part of your solution) and make sure the linker is using it (e.g. Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies property and handling paths properly).

I figure it. I went and downloaded the source from the official site and added it to the project, replacing a few of the files. Had to delete two of the C files that had main functions. I downloaded lua 5.3.6 since i'm not sure this version of sol supports higher.
